# Alternative to closure

Tags: javascript

I am uncertain how to extract some code into a function that needs access to a variable. Most languages have quite clear conventions, but in Javascript everything seems possible.

Here I am doing some calculations with a variable `stack` that I would like to extract to a function.

```
function process() {
  var stack = [];

  while (work_to_do) {
    var chunk = get_next_chunk();

    stack.push(do_some_calculations(stack, chunk));         //
    stack.push(do_more_fancy_calculations(stack, chunk));   // to extract
    stack.push([ stack.pop(), stuff, stack.pop() ]);        //
  }

  stack.push(do_some_calculations(stack, special_chunk));
  stack.push(do_more_fancy_calculations(stack, special_chunk));
  stack.push([ stack.pop(), 'stuff', stack.pop() ]);
}
```

Now I think the usual way (in Javascript) would be to define the function inside of function `process()` to give it access to the closure variable `stack`:

```
function process() {
  var stack = [];

  var do_calculations = function (chunk) {
    stack.push(do_some_calculations(stack, chunk));
    stack.push(do_more_fancy_calculations(stack, chunk));
    stack.push([ stack.pop(), 'stuff', stack.pop() ]);
  }

  while (work_to_do) {
    do_calculations(get_next_chunk());
  }

  do_calculations(special_chunk);
}
```

However, (the real) function `process()` is already quite cluttered and deeply indented, so it might be better to have a pure function on the top level to do those calculations. I could pass `stack` as a parameter:

```
function process() {
  var stack = [];

  while (work_to_do) {
    do_calculations(stack, get_next_chunk());
  }

  do_calculations(stack, special_chunk);
}

function do_calculations (stack, chunk) {
  stack.push(do_some_calculations(stack, chunk));
  stack.push(do_more_fancy_calculations(stack, chunk));
  stack.push([ stack.pop(), 'stuff', stack.pop() ]);
}
```

Or I could treat `stack` like some kind of class object:

```
stack = {
  data: [],
  do_calculations: function (chunk) {
    this.data.push(do_some_calculations(stack, chunk));
    this.data.push(do_more_fancy_calculations(this.data, chunk));
    this.data.push([ this.data.pop(), 'stuff', this.data.pop() ]);
  }
};

function process() {
  while (work_to_do) {
    stack.do_calculations(get_next_chunk());
  }

  stack.do_calculations(special_chunk);
}
```

Is there a best practice how to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no clear-cut better alternative.

If you want an internal function to pick up a variable from the outside so you don't have to pass it in as a parameter, then yes, by definition the internal function will have to be defined lexically within the outer function in order to have it close over the variable(s) from the outer function.

Personally, I don't see the problem in doing this even if the result is that the function grows longer. I don't feel your function is "cluttered and deeply indented".

Of course, if `do_calculations` is ever going to be used in any other context outside `process`, you'll need to define it at the "top" level, in which case you will have to pass in `stack`.

Your third alternative, using an object, is really equivalent in some sense to passing in `stack`--except that you're passing it as `this` (or a property of `this`) instead of as a parameter. To me, that code looks a bit more contorted.

Your second code fragment seems cleanest to me. By the way, it's great to see someone worrying about this kind of detailed factoring issue.

There is one pattern which may or may not be appropriate in this case. Consider:

```
function make_calculator(stack) {
  return function(chunk) {
    stack.push(do_some_calculations(stack, chunk));
    stack.push(do_more_fancy_calculations(stack, chunk));
    stack.push([ stack.pop(), 'stuff', stack.pop() ]);
  };
}

function process() {
  var stack = [];

  var do_calculations = make_calculator(stack);

  while (work_to_do) {
    do_calculations(get_next_chunk());
  }

  do_calculations(special_chunk);
}
```

But this really just passes `stack` in a slightly different fashion. However, it does have the minor advantage that you have to pass `stack` only once, to `make_calculator`, and then the individual calls to `do_calculations` do not have be cluttered up with the extra `stack` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

There's no absolute best practice here.  It all depends upon the circumstances of the code.

If the function doesn't naturally fit into a closure where it has access to the variable it needs, then just pass the variable as an argument to the function when you call it.

That's the generic way for providing a function access to a specific variable (in Javascript and most other languages too).  There's nothing tricky here about this.  Just basic programming.  Javascript has the advantage that if the function is naturally inside another function, then it automatically has access to the parent variables so sometimes you don't have to pass a function everything it needs, but if that structure isn't natural, then just pass the function an argument it needs.

And, keep in mind that objects (which include Arrays) are passed to functions by reference so the function can modify the original if desired.

In addition, if you have a lot of functions that all want access to the same set of data, then sometimes it makes sense to put that data into an object and make all the functions be methods on that object so they can access the data via `this`.